# Add/Remove array object using key found in string array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to implement a function to select multiple items from one and add/remove to another using typescript.

```js
        //data of the display list, each element has same value for text & value.
        private listA: any = {};  
        private listB: any = {};  

        //string array contains the list of name selected
        private selectA: string[] = [];  
        private selectB: string[] = [];

        private addClick: void {

            //remove all from listA that match name found in selectA
            //add to listB all name found in selectA
        }
```

How would I go about to implement this function? I already manage to get the data  (`listA` & `listB`) to populate my list so that is not an issue, my issue is to prepare the data properly for it.

I'm new to typescript & javascript so the syntax is what giving problem now.  I tried to work with `Object.assign()`, delete and couple of other functions I found but no luck so far.

[image]

Comment: Can you update the example with some data in the lists so we can get a better picture of what's going on. `listA` and `listB` are arrays? They're typed as objects right now.

Comment: The listA & listB are list of object that was parsed from a http post response.  to be more percise, it contains two string properties calls text & value.         listA = response.data.map((val: any) => {
                        const el: any = {};
                        el.text = val.name;
                        el.value = val.name;
                        return el;
                    });

Comment: FYI - You can make your original assignment of `listA` more concise if you want.

`this.listA = response.data.map(val => ({ text: val.name, value: val.name }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
  // data of the display list, each element has same value for text & value.
  private listA: any[] = [];
  private listB: any[] = [];

  // string array contains the list of name selected
  private selectA: string[] = [];
  private selectB: string[] = [];

  private addClick(): void {
    // Get items from listA that match selectA.
    const matching = this.listA.filter(x => this.selectA.includes(x.value));

    // Filter listA to only include items that are not a match from selectA.
    this.listA = this.listA.filter(x => !this.selectA.includes(x.value));

    // Add matching items from listA to listB.
    this.listB.push(matching);
  }
```

`this.listB.push(matching)` appends the elements to the end of the array. You can also use `this.listB.unshift(matching)` to prepend them to the start.

Comment: Thanks t8tortolover, this is exactly what I need, I'll try it out with the unshift as well ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand 100% your problem but I tried this and it seems to work check it and we can modify it till reach what you need

```
class Test {     //data of the display list, each element has same value for text & value.
    private listA: any = {a:'a','b':'b'};
    private listB: any = {};

//string array contains the list of name selected
    private selectA: string[] = ['a','b'];
    private selectB: string[] = [];

    public addClick(): void {
        this.selectA.forEach((item) => {
            if (this.listA[item]) {
                this.listB[item] = item;
                delete this.listA[item];
            }
        })
    }

    public showResult(){
        console.log('ListA',this.listA)
        console.log('SelectA',this.selectA)
        console.log('ListB',this.listB)
    }

    //remove all from listA that match name found in selectA
    //add to listB all name found in selectA
}
```

Then we can run this

```
let test = new Test();

test.showResult();
test.addClick();
test.showResult();
```

the Result will be as expected

```
ListA { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
SelectA [ 'a', 'b' ]
ListB {}
ListA {}
SelectA [ 'a', 'b' ]
ListB { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps

1. Iterate through the selected items from selectA
2. Get the index of each item in listA
3. Use splice(param1, param2) method to delete one item at a time from the list
4. Add the item in selectB list as well as listB

Note:- splice() method will mutate the original list ; If you don't want to mutate the list, you can use filter() method